# How to insert an index in string.format?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add an index to `string.format` string, for example:

```
 For i = 1 To Dataset.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
       query_builder.Append(String.Format("@parameter{i}", i))
 Next
```

What I'm trying to achieve is get in a similar result:

```
@parameter1
@parameter2
@parameter3 etc....
```

But I get this error:

> Input string format not correct

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify a numeric value between brackets:

```
For i = 1 To Dataset.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
   query_builder.Append(String.Format("@parameter{0}", i))
Next
```

`{0}` corresponds to the item at index 0 (first item) in the list of parameters to `String.Format`, which is variable `i` in your case.

Answer (score 3):

`query_builder.Append(String.Format("@parameter{i}", i))`

Should be

`query_builder.Append(String.Format("@parameter{0}", i))`

or

`query_builder.AppendFormat("@parameter{0}", i)`

Comment: No. I was using this method on the stringbuilder object when I was using vs2010!

Comment: @Blackwood - no worries!

Comment: I removed my comment to avoid confusion.